# "Debugging" Air drop on Mac

Tags: macos, airdrop

I have a mac the never sees other air drop devices (although they see each other) and no devices can see it. The machine is MBP Retina. Continuity is working on it: you can switch to the app that you are using on an iphone and vise-versa.

This mac arrived with Yosemite and this issue persisted in El Capitan. I've done all the instructions that can be found on different resources like checking firewall, setting discoverable option to *Everyone*, deleting plists, disabling enabling iCloud.

Nothing worked…

Now let's be professional. How can I see any information about air drop? Can I invoke anything from Terminal? Are there any system logs about air drop?

Comment: Airdrop requires both newer hardware and OS, so which Mac model is this?

Comment: @patrix I thought that only an airdrop-supporting hardware can arrive with Yosemite. Anyway, it's last year's MBP Retina. I have an older machine that is working completely fine.

Comment: I see this is still unanswered 4 years later. I also have issues with AirDrop. I can (almost) never AirDrop anything between iPhone 11 Pro, 2013 MBP, 2013 MacBook Air, & iPhone 7. It does work sometimes, but rarely. Everything is set to discoverable by everyone. Bluetooth & WiFi turned on -- on the same network.